# htaccess redirect 301 without sub domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a little task to solve with the `.htaccess`

I want redirect all my old site to a new site.
However, some links must be redirected to a specific *URL* of the new site and all the others at the new domain homepage.
Example:

from

```
url 1 - www.old.com/category-A/article-name-A
url 2 - www.old.com/category-B/article-name-B
url 3 - www.old.com
url 4 - www.old.com/subUrl1
url 5 - www.old.com/subUrl2
```

to

```
url 1 - www.new.com/article-new-A
url 2 - www.new.com/category-B/article-new-B
url 3 - www.new.com
url 4 - www.new.com
url 5 - www.new.com
```

For the first two links I use this code and it works perfectly

```
redirect 301 /category-A/article-name-A www.new.com/article-new-A
redirect 301 /category-B/article-name-B www.new.com/category-B/article-new-B
```

The problem is for the others.
I want that all other subdomains of the site be redirected to the new homepage, without the second part of the *URL* (*/subUrl1*) so you do not have a *404 message*.

If I use

```
redirect 301 / www.new.com
```

I've this result:

```
url 3 - www.new.com
url 4 - www.new.com/subUrl1 (404 page)
url 5 - www.new.com/subUrl2 (404 page)
```

How do I create a general redirect for all these other links?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** *add a question*

I have a subfolder with more link type:

```
domain.com/sub/link1
domain.com/sub/link2
domain.com/sub/link3
domain.com/sub/link4
domain.com/sub/link5
domain.com/sub/link6
```

If I want some links have a custom redirects and instead all the other redirects to the homepage?

Example:

```
redirect 301 domain.com/sub/link1 /sub2
redirect 301 domain.com/sub/link2 /sub3/article1
redirect 301 domain.com/sub/link3 /sub2
other domain.com/sub/ to homepage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
#redirect the main site
redirect 301 /category-A/article-name-A www.new.com/article-new-A
redirect 301 /category-B/article-name-B www.new.com/category-B/article-new-B

#redirect any other domain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com [L,R,NE]
```

The rewriteRule will redirect all other domains (except www.olddomain.com) to http://newdomain.com

Comment: thanks!
another little ask:
I have a subfolder with more link 'domain.com/sub/link1', if I want some links have a custom redirects and instead all the other redirects to the homepage?